# How could we promote JSE when public beta starts?

Tags: discussion

We should have a plan for public beta start, like

- publish on the mailinglist?
- News article on joomla.org?
- post on the forum?
- get extension developers to mail there customers or write a news?
- extend docs.joomla.org with the new Q&A site?
- motivate Joomla magazines to promote the site?

The FAQ in the mail makes it clear:

> Q: How can I help the site succeed?
>
> A: The minute the public beta opens, invite your
>   friends. Spread the word via Twitter, blogs, and email far and wide.
>   Hang out on the site answering incoming questions during the first few
>   hours so that newcomers understand what a great experience a working,
>   popular Stack Exchange site can be.

so we should be prepared for that day!

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with you. I will personally be spreading the word on Facebook, LinkedIn and on my Extensions site (unfortunately I won't be mailing customers though). I assume the PLT will be dealing with the news article on the Joomla site. The thing we need to do is ensure the word is spread well and properly so that people post on the joomla.stackexchange site rather than using the Joomla tag on SO. If nobody else does it then I will update the excerpt/description for the Joomla tag adding a link to the new site

Comment: How or does question migration from SO work in beta phase?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the beta phase. I haven't found anything specific, only a generic overview of migration conditions. Cause of this, I assume it will be the same as what has been described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: They probably wouldn't migrate anything till it was out of Beta. If the Beta failed, they'd lose data or have to transfer it back again.

Answer (score 2):

Before you jump too far down that path, I'd form a management "team" (aka working group) out of the beta participants, and have that team work out what JSE should/could be. From that plan will come how you need to market JSE and also how it may (or may not) slot into the official Joomla organisation structure.

I would be very careful about posting on the forum because this resource directly competes with it and I'm sure there are people that feel threatened by it. Whether that is justified or not doesn't really matter - it's change and some people don't like change.

I think you could promote on the Joomla magazine site but I wouldn't move too fast without a team and a plan.

Comment: You are properly right, so there should be a team that organize this and talks to people. I'm that wrong guy for this job because I don't know anyone in Joomla land^^

Comment: I think we need a mix of people including people that know Joomla but also know how the StackExchange family of sites work and the problems they are trying to solve. And this would seem to be a great way to help you meet new people :) (hint, hint).

Answer (score 1):

We could contact well known Joomla websites and ask them to make a short entry about [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) on their blogs (if they have them). I can think of a few big ones such as k2, nonumber, kunena, easydiscuss, akeeba, sourcecoast, jomsocial,cb etc etc

Perhaps ask them to link to the page that explains how to ask questions first though. People need to know this it's not a discussion forum....but then again it might discourage people :X

Comment: I believe there's also a joomla podcast,  joomlabe

Comment: @ContextSwitch Good examples! A problem I see with contacting websites is that it might take some organization on our part. We don't want people to repeatedly contact the websites, so it would be in our best interests to allocate specific people to websites or make a list of websites that have declined.

Comment: I think it's important to contact those vendors because people are going to be asking questions about their products. So it's in their interests to get involved.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the Forum folk will think of it as lessening their workload, and not be threatened by it!  Of course, I haven't been an active forum mod in like, 4 years?

Still, I can think of a stackexchange site as only a positive thing for Joomla world dominance.  I hope the rest of the project feels the same.

I think it might be helpful to broach the subject with the marketing folks now though.  Jess Dunbar is a good Joomla friend I can get her on the bandwagon.